Delay trim curve animation using geometry nodes
I try to delay the trim curve animation of each plant instances but it doesn't work
as you can see in the attached blend file.

On the left a grid with a bezier curve scattered. It works but doesnt look very random.
On the right side same setup applied to a plant design i have made but it dont work.


I am sorry to write that there is a contradiction in your setup in the sense that you are animating the object ("PlantComplete") that is spawned by the Instance on Points node, while you are expecting each instance to behave independently. By design, the Instance on Points node is replicating the same object. Only position, scale and rotation can be set per instance. You can not control a Trim Curve node  per instance, because each trimmed curve must be a different object.

May I recommend to read this post about controlling a limited subset of spawned objects to give the feeling of a fully random process ? How can I instantiate a procedural node group with different parameters?

I understand... how should i proceed to correct that without having to redo everything ?

I tought that realizing instances was a way to make each instances unique so that the trim curve could have been delayed for each of this new "unique instances"

@ StefLAncien What i dont understand is why does it works in the first setup i did for testing. each bezier curve are delayed properly even tho they are the same "instances" but realized with the realized instance node

The different behaviour between "GridScatterPlants" and "GridScatterTEST" objects comes from the fact that the GN modifier for  "GridScatterTEST" is producing a collection of 400 splines after the Realize Instances node, so you can still apply individually a Trim Curve node. Whereas the "PlantComplete" GN is producing a mesh (made of 9492 vertices, 18649 edges and 9198 faces !). So the underlying spline is complete lost, and there is no chance to apply individually a control.

A workaround could be to "grow" splines without decorations like leaves and flowers, then at each frame, to add the decorations after.

I understand, i will try to change the way its constructed
Thank you
